# How to embed a command in an environment using Expl3?

Tags: expl3, xparse

I wondered how I could apply a command (particularly an Expl3 "bool_if" command) to the content of an environment like this :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N\bool_mytest_appear_bool
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{appearance}{}{
    \bool_if:NT\bool_mytest_appear_bool
    \unknown_command_to_open_group
}{
    \unknown_command_to_end_group
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{appearance}
  Stuff.
\end{appearance}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Doing that you are overwriting the definition of `\emph`. Couldn't you use `emphasize` or something like that?

Comment: @Manuel : It is done, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `environ` package. But may be look at a package to do exactly this (`comment` being one of them, if I remember correctly).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xparse,environ}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \g_mytest_appear_bool
\NewEnviron{emphasize}
 { \bool_if:NT \g_mytest_appear_bool { \BODY } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{emphasize}
  Stuff.
\end{emphasize}

\end{document}
```